# Connecting to cluster with PyMongo fails

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to connect with PyMongo to my cluster But keep getting the following error:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: beasentiment-shard-00-00.iljs4.mongodb.net:27017: ,beasentiment-shard-00-01.iljs4.mongodb.net:27017: ,beasentiment-shard-00-
02.iljs4.mongodb.net:27017: ,
 Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 
5f969972f582ff571e0c4cb1, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, 
servers: [<ServerDescription ('beasentiment-shard-00-00.iljs4.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, 
error=AutoReconnect('beasentiment-shard-00-00.iljs4.mongodb.net:27017: ')>,
 <ServerDescription ('beasentiment-shard-00-01.iljs4.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, 
error=AutoReconnect('beasentiment-shard-00-01.iljs4.mongodb.net:27017: ')>,
 <ServerDescription ('beasentiment-shard-00-02.iljs4.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('beasentiment-shard-00-02.iljs4.mongodb.net:27017: ')>]>
```

I tried several ways but I can't get the DB to connect.

my connection function:

```py
def get_db():
    username = urllib.parse.quote_plus(USER_NAME)
    password = urllib.parse.quote_plus(PASSWORD)

    url = 'mongodb+srv://{}:{}@beasentiment.iljs4.mongodb.net/roark?retryWrites=true&w=majority'.format(username,
                                                                                                        password)

    cluster = MongoClient(url)
    db = cluster['roark']
    return db
```

Comment: What does your `url` resolve to? Here are the guidelines for [ConnectionString URI Format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/index.html#dns-seed-list-connection-format).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you whitelist the calling server's IP address in Atlas.